# Kill process bat

Tags: windows, bat

на сервере weblogic есть 2 ноды иногда память на серваке заканчивается и приходиться перезагружать ноды , написал bat.file который проверяет состояние нодов и если память превышает допустимую норму перезагружает ноду

```
@Echo Off
SET procName=notepad++.exe
SET RAMLimit=20
Set "sum=0"
For /F "Tokens=6-7 Delims=., " %%a In (
    'TaskList /NH /FI "ImageName Eq %procName%"') Do Set/A sum+=%%a%%b

echo %sum%
echo %procName%
echo %RAMLimit%
if %RAMLimit% GEQ %sum%  taskkill /im notepad++.exe* /f >7.txt
Pause
```

этот скрипт работает для эксперимента взял блокнот но когда он завершает задачу блокнота то и сам завершается а мне нужно что бы этот бат работал все время

Comment: *мне нужно что бы этот бат работал все время* BAT/CMD не предназначены для непрерывной работы. То есть зациклить их можно, но тебе точно необходима стопроцентная загрузка процессора? Сделай то же, но, скажем, на VBS. Или запускай раз в минуту через планировщик.\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте метку, например `:BEGIN` и сделайте переход к ней из конца `.bat` файла

```
@Echo Off
:BEGIN
SET procName=notepad++.exe
SET RAMLimit=20
Set "sum=0"
For /F "Tokens=6-7 Delims=., " %%a In (
'TaskList /NH /FI "ImageName Eq %procName%"') Do Set/A sum+=%%a%%b

echo %sum%
echo %procName%
echo %RAMLimit%
if %RAMLimit% GEQ %sum%  taskkill /im notepad++.exe* /f >7.txt
TIMEOUT /T 600
GOTO BEGIN
```

**UPD**
Чтобы не сильно грузило процессор ставим задержку в 600 секунд = 10 минут.

Команда `TIMEOUT` работает в версиях `WINDOWS` начиная с `VISTA`